# error occurred when I execute "self.course.referenceBooks.count"

Tags: ios, core-data

I use Core Data. There are two entity: **Course** and **ReferenceBook**. The relationship is **to-many** among Course and ReferenceBook.

In *CTXCourse.h* :

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class CTXReferenceBook;

@interface CTXCourse : NSManagedObject
//....other property
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSSet *referenceBooks;

@end

@interface CTXCourse (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addReferenceBooksObject:(CTXReferenceBook *)object;
- (void)removeReferenceBooksObject:(CTXReferenceBook *)object;
- (void)addReferenceBooks:(NSSet *)objects;
- (void)removeReferenceBooks:(NSSet *)objects;

@end
```

In a table view controller, I define a NSManagedObjectContext instance and a NSFetchedResultsController instance. There is a push segue to the second view controller ,and pass a course instance.
I want to count the number of books of one course, and execute "`self.course.referenceBooks.count`"

> **Error**:

```
[1066:fb03] -[CTXCourse referenceBooks]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e74af0
[1066:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CTXCourse referenceBooks]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e74af0'
```

But, in CTXCourse.h, I named the referenceBooks to books, then there is no error, that is to say, the result of counting is right.

So, I'm Confused.

Comment: Check your data model file.  I bet it is still named "books" there.  Either that or your database file is old and you need to reinstall the app.

Comment: @borrrden : I try to copy the project, and run it, but the error also occurred. Other,it is no effect to restore the simulator or clear the project, as well.

Comment: What about the first thing I said?  Check your data model file and make sure the property names match all the names in that file.  If you edited your NSManagedObject classes manually, you probably screwed it up.

Comment: @borrrden I wonder whether the keys(property name, which is books) must be same to the name of relationship.